# Best way to downsample (reduce sample rate) non time series data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains data collected every 0.01m down into the earth. Due to its high resolution the resulting size of the dataset is very large. Is there a way in pandas to downsample to 5m intervals thus reducing the size of the dataset?

RESULT  (Every 0.01m)

| Depth_m | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1.34 | 31.7 |
| 1.35 | 31.7 |
| 1.36 | 31.7 |
| 1.37 | 31.9 |
| 1.38 | 31.9 |
| 1.39 | 31.9 |
| 1.40 | 31.9 |
| .... | ..... |
| 44.35 | 32.9 |
| 44.36 | 32.9 |
| 44.37 | 32.9 |

OUTCOME I WANT (Every 5m)

| Depth_m | value |
| --- | --- |
| 5.47 | 31.7 |
| 10.49 | 31.7 |
| 15.51 | 31.7 |
| 20.53 | 31.9 |
| 25.55 | 31.9 |
| 30.57 | 31.9 |
| 35.59 | 31.9 |
| 40.61 | 31.9 |
| 45.63 | 31.9 |

I have tried to use `pandas.resample` but that seems to only work with timeseries data. I think I understand what I must do but not sure how to do it in pandas. Basically I am thinking I need to calculate what the current sampling rate is, in this case 0.01m. Then how many observations are there every 5m. Then I can average the values based on the number of observations and drop the rows. Loop through this process every 5m.

Comment: I downvoted because: question is not reproducible, contains numerical data as image, does not show any attempt of solving the problem.

Comment: Sorry fist time posting trying to make it more clear

Answer (score 2):

There is no `resample` for integer values. As a workaround, you could round the Depth to the nearest 5 and use `groupby` to get the average Value for every 5m depth:

```
>>> df.groupby(df["Depth_m"].apply(lambda x: 5*round(x/5)))["Value"].mean()
Depth_m
0     34.256410
5     34.274549
10    34.564870
15    34.653307
20    34.630739
25    34.517034
30    34.584830
35    34.581162
40    34.620758
45    34.390374
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

###### Input df:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(100)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Depth_m": [i/100 for i in range(134, 4438)],
                   "Value": np.random.randint(30, 40, size=4304)})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Panda's `.iloc` for [selection by position](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-position) coupled with a [slice object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-slice) to downsample. Some care must be taken to ensure you have integer step sizes and not floats when converting from non-integer sample intervals (hence the use of `astype("int")`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

sequence_interval = 0.01
downsampled_interval = 5
step_size = np.round(downsampled_interval / sequence_interval).astype("int")

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Depth_m": np.arange(131, 4438) / 100,
        "value": np.random.random(size=4307),
    }
)

downsampled_df = df.iloc[::step_size, :]
print(downsampled_df)
```

The result is

```
      Depth_m     value
0        1.31  0.357536
500      6.31  0.384327
1000    11.31  0.302109
1500    16.31  0.200971
2000    21.31  0.689973
2500    26.31  0.712869
3000    31.31  0.776306
3500    36.31  0.221901
4000    41.31  0.661378
```

Answer (score 0):

Understanding that it's been a little while since the original question, presently there's an [`aggregate_downsample()`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.timeseries.aggregate_downsample.html#astropy.timeseries.aggregate_downsample) function available in the [Time Series](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/timeseries/index.html) support in [Astropy](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/index.html).

Of course, the application might vary somewhat, depending on the format of the input dataset.

In one approach with the sample data, known limitations:

- This assumes that the provided sampling rate is consistent across the dataset - as provided, 0.01 minutes. Astropy does offer support for uneven sampling rates, however.
- The time series and binning functions in Astropy may require some form of a *start time*, as one form of possible input. For purpose of simplicity, the example below uses `datetime.now()`. The same functions may support a variety of other inputs, including series of time values.

Downsampling to a five minute duration:

```py
from datetime import datetime
from astropy.timeseries import TimeSeries, aggregate_downsample
from astropy import units as u
import numpy as np

first_sample_dt = datetime.now()
in_sample_rate = u.min * 0.01

out_sample_rate = 5 *  u.min

depth_nd = np.array([1.34, 1.35, 1.36, 1.37, 1.38, 1.39, 1.40])
val_nd =   np.array([31.7, 31.7, 31.7, 31.9, 31.9, 31.9, 31.9])

data_series = TimeSeries(
    data = {"depth": depth_nd, "val": val_nd},
    time_start = first_sample_dt,
    time_delta = in_sample_rate
)

downsampled = aggregate_downsample(
     data_series, 
     time_bin_size = out_sample_rate
)
```

For purpose of illustration, the downsampled data when `out_sample_rate = 0.02 *  u.min` using [Astropy time units](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/time/index.html):

```py
<BinnedTimeSeries length=3>
      time_bin_start       time_bin_size       depth               val        
                                min                                           
           Time               float64         float64            float64      
-------------------------- ------------- ------------------ ------------------
2024-03-17 06:06:56.806402          0.02 1.3450000000000002               31.7
2024-03-17 06:06:58.006402          0.02 1.3650000000000002 31.799999999999997
2024-03-17 06:06:59.206402          0.02               1.39 31.899999999999995
```

The Astropy BinnedTimeSeries data can be converted to a Pandas DataFrame

```py
>>>  downsampled.to_pandas()
                            time_bin_size  depth   val
time_bin_start                                        
2024-03-17 06:06:56.806402           0.02  1.345  31.7
2024-03-17 06:06:58.006402           0.02  1.365  31.8
2024-03-17 06:06:59.206402           0.02  1.390  31.9
```

Alternately, back to numpy, for 'downsampled' as the 0.02 minute data:

```py
>>> downsampled['val'].value
masked_array(data=[31.7, 31.799999999999997, 31.899999999999995],
             mask=[False, False, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)

>>> type(downsampled['val'].value)
numpy.ma.core.MaskedArray
```

Astropy's [`aggregate_downsample()`](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.timeseries.aggregate_downsample.html#astropy.timeseries.aggregate_downsample) function also offers a specific `aggregate_func` arg, to determine how the data is downsampled. By default, the downsampling uses `np.nanmean`